# Will AMD continue to update the legacy Fglrx driver?

Tags: drivers, ati

I have a ATI/AMD HD3450, and clearly it's not supported by the Proprietary drivers in 12.10.

However, there is a legacy driver, which is also not supported at this time.

Is this legacy driver kept up to date from time to time, so that I will be able to use it at some time in the future? Or must I remain with the open source drivers if I don't also wish to downgrade X?

Comment: Those Drivers are closed-source and ubuntu engineers and other guys cant update and fix it . you should ask it on [AMD Forums](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx). And open source drivers are everytime better because when a problem starts , it couldt care in 1-2 hour

Comment: I know the drivers are closed source and that the Ubuntu developers can't fix them. However companies usually have strategies that are shared with the developers of the concerned Operating Systems. That's what I'm really asking about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AMD support page, It seems that they are still supporting with "application specific issues and critical updates"

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

> The reason for the shift in support policy is largely due to the fact that the AMD Radeon HD 4000, AMD Radeon HD 3000, and AMD Radeon HD 2000 Series have been optimized to their maximum potential from a performance and feature perspective.

But, It looks like the update came from **7/24/2012** and that is a general linux driver, so there could be a number of specific Ubuntu issues.

They have a link to report specific issues with the driver on the page (not tech support)

So, It looks like it wasn't totally abandoned yet...

Comment: Since AMD is undergoing massive layoffs and just laid off their entire Linux support lab in Germany[1], I wouldn't count on too many more updates for these old drivers.  [1]- http://www.engadget.com/2012/11/09/amd-shutters-linux-support-lab-as-part-of-company-wide-layoffs/

Comment: Hm, sure seems like that may be the case, hopefully this isn't the end of linux support, http://www.networkworld.com/news/2012/110712-amd-open-source-264062.html "The closure of the OSRC in no way speaks to a lack of commitment by AMD to development of AMD optimized Linux kernels or supporting drivers." ...