# How to deal with bugs in proprietary legacy driver?

Tags: ati, fglrx, bug-reporting, proprietary

I'm facing serious bugs in my proprietary AMD/ATI display drivers. Where do I report bugs regarding such drivers? Do proprietary drivers get modified by community to provide latest fixes at the expense of decreased stability?

This https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs didn't answer my question.

Related:
[Will AMD continue to update the legacy Fglrx driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220266/will-amd-continue-to-update-the-legacy-fglrx-driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page, you can [report bugs](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) to ATI/AMD on their bug tracker:

- http://ati.cchtml.com/

However they state:

> These sites are community resources, and are not supported by, or
>   affiliated with AMD in any way

There appears to be no supported way for community members to report bugs other than through that or via your distribution.

> Do proprietary drivers get modified by community to provide latest fixes at the expense of decreased stability?

No, those drivers are closed source and community members don't have access to the source code.